# Erro sqlalchemy 1044

Tags: mysql, python

Tenho uma aplicação em Python que se conecta com um banco Mysql através de Sqlalchemy, porem não fui eu quem desenvolvi.

Ao migrar o banco para um outro servidor(aws.rds ⇢ go daddy), mudei a *string* de conexão para o novo servidor e aparentemente o banco está configurado corretamente, pois consigo conectá-lo ao Workbench, mas quando rodo a aplicação ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError OperationalError: (OperationalError)
>   (1044, "Access denied for user 'xpto'@'%' to database 'otpx'") None
>   None.

Como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui.
No Mysql rodei o seguinte código:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on nome_banco.* TO user'@'api.nomedohost.com.br' IDENTIFIED BY 'senha'